# What does negative count of forks mean?

Tags: github

I created a new repository that appears to have negative count of forks.

[image: screenshot-github]

Is this a UI bug or something I should be concerned about before the team starts working in this repo?

If I go to `https://github.com/<orgname>/<reponame>/forks` (the forks page under the insight tab) then it says that the repo has no forks.

So I think this is a UI bug, but I am slightly hesitant to tell the team to start use the repo before I know what is going on.

Comment: if you think it is a bug in github, you should create a ticket there

Comment: That's currently my best theory, but thought of asking here first if there is another explanation

Comment: GitHub support confirmed with me that this is a bug but also that it is only a UI bug.